# How need mapping errors in a Formik?

Tags: reactjs, formik

Simplified version of the code:

```
<Formik>
      {({ errors, touched }) => (
        <Form className="auth__form">
          <div>
            {inputs.map(input => (
                <Field name={input.name} validate={input.validator} placeholder=t(`head.authentication.${input.name}`)} />
                {errors[input.name] && touched[input.name] &&
                  <span className="error_text">
                    {t(`head.authentication.errors.${input.name}.${errors[input.name]}`)}
                  </span>
                }
                {/* <ErrorMessage name={input.name} /> */}
              </>
            ))}
          </div>
        </Form>
      )}
    </Formik>
```

Errors[input.name] and touched[input.name] give error: **Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'FormikTouched<{ mailing: boolean; name: string; login: string; password: string; email: string; }>'.**

I tried to use , but it doesn't work with i18next.
I also tried to change the types in the library, which helped, but is not a good solution

Comment: Did you check this? https://react.i18next.com/latest/typescript#type-errors